# open a private chat window on a button click

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, socket.io, chat

I am trying to implement a one to one chat between two users using `node js` and `socket.io`. I am trying to open a `chatroom` on the click of `find friend` `button` and `username` is entered in the text field `chatGroupName`.
After clicking on the button it will check if the 'user' is 'online' which it will get from 'onlineusers' array, then i want to display chat window with both the 'user' messaging privatly.Sorry for the messy code.

server side script-->
*app.js*

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var nsp = io.of('/my-namespace');
var PORT = 8000;
users = [];
connections = [];
onlineusers = [];
rooms = [];
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/chat', (req, res) => {

    res.render("chat") //pick the index.ejs file 
})

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('New user connected!')
    // console.log(socket.client.id)
    connections.push(socket);
    console.log('Connected : %s sockets connected', connections.length)


    //disconnect user
    socket.on('disconnect', function (data) {
        // if (!socket.username) return;
        users.splice(users.indexOf(socket.username), 1);
        // updateUsernames();
        connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket), 1);
        console.log('Disconnected : %s sockets connected', connections.length)
    });

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    socket.on('find_friend',function(data){
        for(var i = 1; i <= onlineusers.length; i++){
           // console.log(onlineusers.length)
            console.log( "onlineusers",onlineusers[i])

            if(data == onlineusers[i] && i < onlineusers.length ){
               // console.log(true)
                socket.emit('chat',onlineusers[i]);
            }
            else {
                console.log('user not online')
            }
        }  
    })
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //new message
    socket.on('new_message', (data) => {

        io.sockets.emit('new_message', {
            message: JSON.stringify(data),
            username: socket.username
        });
    })


    //broadcast message
    socket.on("typing", (data) => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('typing', {
            username: socket.username
        });
    })


    // new user
    socket.on('new_user', (data, callback) => {

        callback(true);
        socket.username = data;
        users.push({
             id: socket.id,
             username: socket.username
        });
        onlineusers.push(data);
        //console.log(onlineusers)
        updateUsernames();
    })

    //update user list function
    function updateUsernames() {
         io.sockets.emit('get_users', onlineusers);
    }

//create a new room
    socket.on('new_room', (data, callback) => {
        callback(true);
        rooms.push(data);
        socket.join(data);
        socket.emit("sucess","you join the room");
        //console.log(users)
        updateRoomNames();
    })

    //update user list function
    function updateRoomNames() {
         io.sockets.emit('get_room', rooms);
    }



})


//server listen to the port
server.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log('server is connected to the port : ' + PORT)
})
```

client side script -->chat.js

```
$(function () {
    //make connection
    console.log("hello")
    var socket = io() //.connect('http://localhost:8000')
    //buttons and inputs
    var message = $("#message")
    var username = $("#username")
    var send_message = $("#send_message")
    var login = $('#Login')
    var chatroom = $("#chatroom")
    var feedback = $("#feedback")
    var userForm = $("#userForm")
    var userFormArea = $("#userFormArea")
    var messageArea = $("messageArea")
    var users = $("#users")
    var rooms = $('#myDropdown')
    var chatGroupName = $("#chatGroupName")
    var createChatGroup = $("#createChatGroup")
    var joinChatGroup = $("#joinChatGroup")
    var friendName = $('#friendName')
    var upper_name = $('#upper_name')

    //Emit message
    send_message.click(function () {
        socket.emit('new_message', {
            message: message.val()
        })
        message.val(''); //empty the message variable
    })

    socket.emit('create', 'room1');


    //new user
    login.click(function () {
        socket.emit('new_user', username.val(), function (data) {
            console.log(data)
            if (data) {
                userFormArea.hide();
                // console.log("hide userform")
                document.getElementById('messageArea').style.display = "block";
                //  console.log('show message area')
            }
        })
        username.val(''); //empty the message variable
    })

    //create chat group
    createChatGroup.click(function () {
        socket.emit('new_room', chatGroupName.val(), function (data) {
            console.log(data)
            if (data) {
                document.getElementById('messageArea').style.display = "block";
                // socket.emit('create', chatGroupName.val())
                //  console.log('show message area')
            }
        })
        chatGroupName.val(''); //empty the message variable
    })
    joinChatGroup.click(function () {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
        window.onclick = function (event) {
            if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

                var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                    var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                    if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    })
     //here is the problem code
    ///////////////////////////////////*TEST1* */
    friendName.click(function () {
        socket.emit('find_friend', chatGroupName.val())
    })
     //
    socket.on('chat', (data) => {
        console.log(data)
        // document.getElementById('messageArea').style.display = "block";
        if (data) {
            var html = '<h1 class = "upper_name">' + data + '</h1>';

           // socket.on(data).emit(document.getElementById('messageArea').style.display = "block");
            upper_name.html(html);
            document.getElementById('upper_name').style.display = "block";
        }
    })


    //////////////////////////////////TEST 1 END///
    // List of users
    socket.on('get_users', function (data) {
        var html = '';
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            html += '<li class = "list-group-item">' + data[i] + '</li>';
        }
        users.html(html);
    })

    //list of rooms
    socket.on('get_room', function (data) {
        var html = '';
        for (i = 1; i <= data.length; i++) {
            html += '<a class = "list-group-item">' + data[i] + '</a>';
        }
        rooms.html(html);
    })

    //Listen on new_message
    socket.on("new_message", (data) => {
        feedback.html('');
        message.val('');
        chatroom.append("<p class='message'>" + data.username + ": " + data.message + "</p>")
    })

    //Emit typing
    message.bind("keypress", () => {
        socket.emit('typing', username)
    })

    //Listen on typing
    socket.on('typing', (data) => {
        feedback.html("<p><i>" + data.username + " is typing a message..." + "</i></p>")
    })



    //socket.emit('login',{userId:'YourUserID'});
});



/************************************************************* */
```

my html file--> chat.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" const="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <title>Simple Chat App</title>

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Super Chat</h1>
  </header>
  <div id="userFormArea" style="margin-top: 30px" ;>
    <section>
      <label class="vertical-align">Enter username</label>
      <input id="username" class="vertical-align" type="text" />
      <button id="Login" class="vertical-align" type="button">Login</button>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div id="messageArea" style="display:none";>
    <div class="split left">
    <div id = "groupchat">
        <input id="chatGroupName" class="dropbtn" type="text" placeholder="Find people,group name..." />
        <button id="createChatGroup" class="dropbtn" type="button">Create group</button>
        <button class="dropbtn" id = "friendName">Enter friend's name</button>   
        <div class = "dropdown"><button id="joinChatGroup" class="dropbtn" type="button">Join group</button></div>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
           <!-- <a href="#home">Home</a>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>-->
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="well">
      <h3>Online Users</h3>
      <!--<input id="chat_with" class="vertical-align" type="text" placeholder="Enter name to chat with..." />-->

      <ul >
        <li>
          <a href = # class="list_group" id="users" ></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
<div class="split right">
  <div id ="upper_name">

  </div>
  <div id = "chat">
      <section id="chatroom">
          <section id="feedback"></section>
        </section>

        <section id="input_zone">
          <input id="message" class="vertical-align" type="text" />
          <button id="send_message" class="vertical-align" type="button">Send</button>
        </section>
  </div>

    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="chat.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

I may not able to explain the problem correctly because i really don't know about this.(this may help:trying to implement skype like format where when you click on online user the chat window get open.). Any help will appreciated.